# Как в Lua передать путь к файлу?

Tags: lua

Мне нужно прочитать с файла в функции. файл в той же папке что и код. 
Я передаю так : `local inputFileName = [[ts.txt]]`
Но выдает ошибку:

> ts.txt: No such file or directory)

Comment: Передавайте абсолютный путь к файлу и не будет проблем.

Comment: @zed наведите пример. может я не правильно передаю. пробывал

Comment: @zed local inputFileName = [[C:/ts.txt]] так  работает. Но мне  не нужно  захаркодженно

Comment: @zed и так делал [[../ts.txt]]

Comment: А запускаете вы скрипт из какой папки?

Comment: @Ainar-G D:\Project\

Comment: и в  этой папке у меня все и файлы txt и файл с кодом..... Но мне нужно показывать эту  прогу  на PC в универе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы запускаете скрипт из той же директории, всё должно рабоать.
Если вы в другой директории, то либо перейдите в неё:

```sh
$ cd /path/to/dir
$ ls
script.lua
ts.txt
$ lua ./script.lua
```

Либо прописывайте абсолютный путь.  Путь можно прописать в переменной
окружения:

```sh
# Unix:
export FILES_PATH="/path/to/dir"
```

```
:: Windows:
SET FILES_PATH="/path/to/dir"
```

И получить в скрипте:

```lua
local dir = os.getenv("FILES_PATH")
path = dir .. "/" .. "ts.txt"
```

Comment: я нигде не  запускаю скрипт. я просто в функции создаю переменную и в нее передаю путь  [[ts.txt]]. Или нужно  запускать скрипт  обязательно?

Comment: либо сюда передаю local file = io.open([[ts.txt], "w")

Comment: Эм…  Как же вы не запускаете скрипт, если вы получаете ошибку?

Comment: какой скрипт?  я никакой скрипт не запускаю)

Comment: Ваша программа на языке луа — это скрипт.  Вы запускаете её и получаете ошибку.  Вы написали про эту ошибку в оригинальном посте.

Comment: Перефразируюю. local file = io.open([[D:/ts.txt], "w") так  работает. Но я  хочу  чтобы оно везде  работало . не  только у меня на компе. Поэтому я файл  занес в папку  с кодом

Comment: все я понял.  да когда я  напишу local file = io.open([[ts.txt], "w") выдает ошибку. если я напишу local file = io.open([[D:/ts.txt], "w")  все работает

Comment: У меня все файлы в  одной папке. и странно почему не  работает.

Comment: Последний раз.  _Не важно,_ что скрипт и файл в одной директории.  _Важно_ то, в какой директории находитесь вы.  Ваша **рабочая директория.**  Если вы не знаете, что это такое, то вам нужно воспользоваться поисковиком.

Comment: я использую ZeroBrain studio и я  не  знаю какая рабочая  директория  используется.....

Comment: Иисусе, ну с этого бы и начинали!  В вопросе же нету ничего о том, что вы используете _IDE_!  Открывайте `CMD.EXE`, перемещайтесь в директорию с файлом и скриптом, и там запускайте `lua .\script_name.lua` или как там это на _Windows_.

Comment: сделал так как вы написали и у меня файл с кодом запустился в текстовом редакторе

Comment: Смотрите если например  мой  друг  захочет  у себя на компе  запутить мой код.  то ему что тоже в cmd все  это  нужно  делать? Страно на С++ все  проще с этим....

Comment: Вы что-то неверно сделали.  Вам надо проверить, что код работает в нормальном режиме, то есть из командной строки, с нужной рабочей директорией.  Если это так, то вам надо искать, где в этой вашей _IDE_ устанавливается рабочая директория.

Comment: может она  там  где и lua.exe ?

Comment: C:\Users\vova\Downloads\ZeroBraneStudio\bin\lua.exe:

Comment: все я сделал. спасибо

Comment: @VovaMakarovych *Страно на С++ все проще с этим...* ну так и пишите на С++, если вам проще. А в lua и других интерпретируемых языках вот так. И вашему другу, если он захочет запустить ваш скрипт ещё и скачать и установить lua придётся.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо открыть файл, который лежит в той же папке, что и текущий скрипт, то вам надо сперва определить полный путь к вашему скрипту, а затем, используя его, сконструировать и передать полный путь к файлу.

Определить путь к скрипту можно [несколькими способами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380820/get-containing-path-of-lua-file), например вот так:

```
function script_path()
   local str = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
   return str:match("(.*[/\\])") or ".\\"
end
```

Ну а дальше всё просто:

```
local inputFileName = script_path() .. "ts.txt"
```

Comment: В регулярках лучше, наверное, использовать неформатированные строки: `[=[(.*[/\])]=]`.

Comment: @zed а попроще можно как  то. я же не объясню преподу как  функция  работает.